# Как показать блок полностью при первом клике и раскрыть его на весь экран при повторном?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как реализовать плавное выдвижение блока с помощью Jquery? Но нужно не просто скрыть/показать, а изначально должна быть видна верхняя часть блока. При нажатии на стрелочку раскрывается остальная часть блока и при повторном нажатии открывается на весь экран.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.arrow').on('click', function() { // при нажатии на стрелку
  if (!$('.block').hasClass('block__active')) { // если блок закрыт
    $('.block').addClass('block__active'); // добавляем ему дополнительный класс и частично открываем его
    $('.close').addClass('close__active'); // активируем крестик для закрытия блока
  } else { // если блок частично открыт
    $('.block').removeClass('block__active'); // убираем ему этот класс
    $('.block').addClass('block__window'); // добавляем ему дополнительный класс и полностью открываем его
    $('.arrow').hide(); // убираем стрелку
  }
});
$('.close').on('click', function() { // при нажатии на крестик
  $('.block').removeClass('block__window').removeClass('block__active'); // удаляем у блока все дополнительные классы и закрываем его
  $('.close').removeClass('close__active'); // убираем крестик
  $('.arrow').show(); // показываем стрелку
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: midnightblue;
}

.block {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.block__active {
  bottom: 0;
  animation: block__active 0.5s;
}

@keyframes block__active {
  0% {
    bottom: -30%;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

.block__window {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: block__window 0.5s;
}

@keyframes block__window {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.arrow {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 23px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.close__active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"><span class="arrow"></span><span class="close"></span></div>
```